Why I cannot find export kit on my figma?
I created a UI layout for my app on Figma. I want to export it to be directly used in Android Studio, and I tried to search on YouTube how. However, when I tried to follow their steps, I could not find the export kit they used for exporting the UI.

Is there another way of exporting the UI of my app to be used in Android Studio? Any response is appreciated.
